# $_GET is not working with radio buttons

Tags: php, forms, get, radio-button

Does anyone know why this code will not work? I simply want to print which radio button is selected. It always prints 'Null' no matter what is selected. PHP code is below.

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','student','student') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('vgs',$conn);

//Get Question 1
if (isset($_GET["q1option"])) 
{
    $q1option = $_GET["q1option"];
} 
else 
{
    $q1option = "Null";
}
//Process Question 1
echo "".$q1option;
```

The HTML code is below.

```
<form action="" method="get" >
<div id="Q1">
<label><input type="radio" name="q1option" value="Less_than_16" />Less than 16</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="q1option" value="16_or_more" />16 or more</label>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Note I have many tables in the 'vgs' database, if that makes a difference.

Thank you,

Daniel

*Additional Code*

HTML below

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="result();" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Embedded JavaScript below. It uses http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

```
function result()
{
    $('#Suggestion').load('process_answers.php');
}
```

Comment: Run a `var_dump($_GET)` or a `print_r($_GET)` to see if what's in _GET is what you expect.

Comment: Your code seems to be running fine on my local server. You are submitting the form right? Your url should have something like this at the end of it `?q1option=16_or_more`

Comment: Standard scoldings and warnings about deprecated functions...

Comment: @AlexHowansky I used var_dump and it displayed 'Null' when I had an option selected.

Comment: @Jako I am not actually submitting the form. I will add some more code above to show you what I am doing. I am using AJAX. I know it should have that but it doesn't.

Comment: Hi guys. I still haven't got the issue sorted. RobB was on to something I think. Could you please look at our comments on his answer below? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your submit button is outside of the `<form>` tag, it should be within the form:

```
<form action="" method="get" >
<div id="Q1">
<label><input type="radio" name="q1option" value="Less_than_16" />Less than 16</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="q1option" value="16_or_more" />16 or more</label>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always getting `Null` in return because your query string is not being attached anywhere.  If you are using AJAX, you need to pass the query string data.  Your cycle is not working properly because of a misconfiguration.

Take the following code:

```
//Get Question 1
if (isset($_GET["q1option"])) 
{
    $q1option = $_GET["q1option"];
} 
else 
{
    $q1option = "Null";
}
```

Using $_GET will attempt to extract from your query string a variable labeled 'q1option'.  If this variable is not set, then return 'Null'.  So your code is working as expected as it is currently structured.

If you want to pass the variable between pages you will either need to submit the form and the variable will be automatically passed, or you need to modify your jQuery to allow for the passing and processing behind the scenes of your variable.  Once processed, you would then handle the results accordingly and render them to the client as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still learning AJAX. How would I do what you are suggesting (ie. pass the query string data)?

Comment: What does your 'process_answers.php' file actually do?  I would suggest utilizing $.getJSON() and pass the variable to your handler file.  Your handler file would then process the passed variables, validate them, and render a response back to the client, which in this case is your script containing $.getJSON().

Comment: The 'process_answers.php' file will carry out many mysql queries based on the answers to the questions. There are 5 questions. The php code at the top of my question is the contents of that file.

I'm sorry, but could you step me through how to do what you suggested in your previous comment. I appreciate you helping me with this.

Comment: Hi RobB, I just saw the paragraph you added. Unfortunately, I am still lost. Could you please talk me through exactly what I must do. I am a student in this stuff. I think I am just missing something in my JavaScript. The code that is in the php... does that need to be converted to javascript and placed below the existing javascript code? Thanks.